# Gibbs sampling for mixed variables

Tags: gibbs

Let X a continous variable and Y a binary variable with joint distribution :
$$p(x,y;\beta,\rho_1,\rho_2,\phi_1,\phi_2)=\frac{1}{Z(\beta,\rho_1,\rho_2,\phi_1,\phi_2)}\exp(-0.5 \beta x^2+1_{y=0}\rho_1 x+1_{y=1} \rho_2 x+1_{y=0} \phi_1+1_{y=1} \phi_2)$$ with Z a normalising constant.

The conditional of X given Y is a Gaussian depending on Y and the conditional of Y given X is a Bernoulli variable whose probability $P(Y=1)$ is depending on X.

Is it possible to use Gibbs sampling?

Comment: How does this example differ from the answers to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210741/? (I'd vote to close this as a duplicate but on the other hand @Glen_b suggested in comments that the OP posts the specific example as a separate question)

Comment: More precisely there are 2 questions : Are they some conditions in order to use Gibbs sampling? Does the variables in the example fulfill these conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plainly you could use Gibbs sampling to generate from $(X,Y)$; there's nothing about the structure here that's out of the ordinary.

By inspection, the conditional distribution of $X|Y=y$ is normal; the conditional distribution of $Y|X=x$ is Bernoulli.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I couldn't use it because changing the variable order gives me different results.

Comment: I can't see why that should happen

Comment: I have asked a new question about this problem : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210872/gibbs-sampling-in-r